# How to check the matching accuracy of a sentence to a specific tag pattern in Python with NLTK

Tags: python, regex, nltk

Currently I am working on a Natural Language Processing project.So in my project, I wanted to check the matching accuracy of sentence to specific tag pattern.
Actually I wanted to do the following thing.
I have list of Regexp Tag patterns like:

```
{<DT|PP\$>?<JJ>*<NN>}
{<JJ>*<NN>}
{<NN>}
{<DT|PP\$>?<JJ>*<NN>*<V>}
```

And also I have a list of sentences.Like

```
Design a questionnaire to gather information.
Conduct an investigation to produce information to support a view.
Construct a graph to illustrate selected information
What could be changed to improve the performances?
```

So what I want is to check whether how far the sentences(Actually most of the time those sentences are questions) matches with those tag patterns.So I wanted to have matching accuracy in numerical value.Actually I don't know whether it is possible or not in python with NLTK.So can some help me to figure it out.Thanking you.

Comment: Can you add an example of your sentences?

Comment: Ok.I updated question..Thank you

Comment: It's certainly possible, but you'll have to explain exactly what you have and what you want to count. Have you tagged your sentences with the regexp tagger? Do you also have the correct ("gold standard") tags available? Is percentage of all words that are correctly tagged good enough?

Comment: Actually I wanted to identify some common tag pattern for my question list.This is why I am looking for matching values of sentences to each tag pattern.Those tag patterns are arbitrary patterns.So I wanted know how far my sentences are matches to each tag pattern.Suppose for example let's say first question matches  80% to the first tag pattern and 50% to the second tag pattern.So likewise I wanted to get the matching accuracy.

Comment: Do you really need POS tag patterns to get sentence similarity? https://groups.google.com/d/forum/sts-semeval Also, try not to spam similar questions on SO, i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33318975/how-to-get-common-tag-pattern-for-sentences-list-in-python-with-nltk =)

Comment: @Punuth, your response didn't answer any of my questions.