# How to get common tag pattern for sentences list in python with NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, tagging

Here I have a list of sentences.With NLTK I can tag the sentence and get the tag pattern of that sentences. So as like this I can get the tag patterns for the whole list.But what I wanted is to identify the common tag patterns which most sentences get matched.For example:

- What is encapsulation

  ```
  tag pattern : {<WP><VBZ><NN>}
  ```
- How was your wedding

  ```
  tag pattern : {<WRB><VBD><PRP$><NN>}
  ```
- What is your plan today

  ```
  tag pattern : {<WP><VBZ><PRP$><NN><NN>}
  ```

So the common tag pattern(Combining regexp tagger) for above threes sentences is:

```
{<W.+><V.+><PRP.?>?<NN>+} - One "Wh" word,one verb,zero or one pronoun,one or many nouns
```

So I want to generalize the tag patterns of sentences to common ones.This is the thing what I wanted to do..

So can someone tell me how to do that?

Comment: Can you give an example of your expected output?

Comment: I don't think there's an easy answer to this – at least I wouldn't know one. You might find help in one of the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196049/regular-expression-generator-reducer).

Comment: Similar to @lenz response, I have tried some strings and ngrams based methods but nothing would come close to a use-able pattern recognizing model in any setting =( Possibly someone else might know how to do that.

Comment: @alvas, I'm surprised you thought it would be worth trying! The most I would recommend along these lines is tag ngrams. I.e., collect all 4- or 5-tuples of tags occurring within a sentence. But I'd still use statistics rather than match all ngrams on an equal basis.

Comment: @alexis, I spent 15 mins on it before giving up ;P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are after a regexp (with quantifiers) that will match all the different tag sequences in your data. While this is not an easy problem, 
I suspect that your goal is to find a pattern that captures the sequences that are legal sentences, is this right?

If so, regexps (and finite-state approaches in general) are inherently the wrong tool for the job. To even get a start on characterizing your sentence collection, you need to look at context-free grammars. Take a look at the NLTK's materials on the topic.